# jspdf first PDF page is blank

Tags: jspdf

Im trying to get my jspdf to not save a blank page PDF. I been trying many examples, but nothing works :(. My table content is saved correct, with a image on the second page of the PDF, but my first page is blank.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('o', 'pt', 'a6');
//pdf.autoTable(this.columns, this.data);
//var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;    
//var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
pdf.addPage('1800','900');
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 120, 40, 120, 100);
pdf.setTextColor(0,0,0);
pdf.text(120, 20, 'BOOKINGS');
pdf.setFontSize(22);    
// 'o', 'pt', 'a4'
// 'p', 'pt', 'letter'
// source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
// to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
source = jQuery('.dataTables_wrapper')[0];
// we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
// ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
// There is no support for any other type of selectors 
// (class, of compound) at this time.
specialElementHandlers = {
    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
        return true
    }
};
margins = {
    top: 120,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 2000
};
// all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
// 'inches' in this case
pdf.fromHTML(
source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
margins.left, // x coord
margins.top, { // y coord
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},

function (dispose) {
    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('bookings.pdf');
}, margins);
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first page is blank because adding a page is the first call you make after calling the `jsPDF` constructor. The constructor does already create a (first) blank page. To get rid of the additional empty page at the start of the document, either delete the first page calling `doc.deletePage(1)`, or do not add a page after the constructor is being called.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is how I'm creating mine now `this.pdfDoc = new jsPDF().deletePage(1)`